# Why is the rax register zeroed out?

Tags: c++, multithreading, assembly, x86-64

I'm writing a multithreaded C++ program using a 3rd party library GDAL. My program works correctly most of the time, but about every 800 runs or so I get an unexplained segfault within the 3rd party library at the instruction indicated below. It would appear that the segfault occurs due to a null pointer dereference ( %rax is being dereferenced, but it is an invalid dereference because %rax is zero). I am unclear on how this can happen though because the `mov    0x50(%r13),%rax` instruction previously loads a valid address of a member variable (0x7fffe86eb8e0 + 0x50 = 0x7fffe86eb930) into %rax ... no other instruction touches %rax before the crash.

Source line of crash and disassembly from the 3rd party library (crash location denoted with '=>'):

```
u.papoBlocks[nBlockIndex] = poBlock;   // poBlock is a pointer to an object
                                       // u.papoBlocks is an array of pointers. 
                                       // nBlockIndex is the value "2", stored in %rbx


   0x00007ffff4227393 <+51>:    mov    0x50(%r13),%rax
   0x00007ffff4227397 <+55>:    lea    (%rbx,%r14,1),%ebx
   0x00007ffff422739b <+59>:    movslq %ebx,%rbx
=> 0x00007ffff422739e <+62>:    mov    %r12,(%rax,%rbx,8)
```

Below find the registers at the time of the fault.

```
rax            0x0                 0                  
rbx            0x2                 2                  // the offset into the array
r12            0x7fffcd30f9c0      140736635926976    // %r12 contains the pointer "poBlock"
r13            0x7fffe86eb8e0      140737092958432    // %r13 contains the "this" pointer
r14            0x0                 0
```

The C++ code is simply assigning a pointer to a member of an array of pointers. I've already validated that the array is allocated properly.

```
(gdb) print &this->u                  
$21 = (GDALArrayBandBlockCache::u *) 0x7fffe86eb930
(gdb) print u.papoBlocks[2]
$22 = (GDALRasterBlock *) 0x0
(gdb) print u.papoBlocks   
$23 = (GDALRasterBlock **) 0x7fffe91fb680
```

This seems impossible to me. Can anyone explain why %rax is assigned a legitimate value and two instructions later %rax contains 0 ?

Comment: What is `x/xa 0x7fffe86eb930`?

Comment: Looks like you've stumbled into undefined behavior land.  Without a [mre] it will be difficult to give you direction to defined behavior land.

Comment: @Jester 
`(gdb) x/xa 0x7fffe86eb930
0x7fffe86eb930: 0x7fffe91fb680`

Comment: Is this part of a loop? Any other way to get back to the faulting line, not coming from the load directly?

Comment: @Jester It is indeed part of a loop. In this case the code is iterating over blocks of data, and this fault occurs in the function that stores the newly loaded block `poBlock` in an array of cached blocks `u.papoBlocks`. The only way I've been able to reproduce is to run the program in a loop hundreds of times.

Comment: I mean is there a jump to the faulting line that skips the `mov    0x50(%r13),%rax`? So `rax` is not changing in this 4 instruction block, rather, it is changed later and code gets back to the faulting instruction.

Comment: @Jester no this is not such a loop. The whole function can be seen here: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/961acd83649b28c4ab22813f0a55533c34db1d02/gdal/gcore/gdalarraybandblockcache.cpp#L209

Comment: Well, the value might have been NULL when the `mov` executed but has since been updated by another thread. You could put a conditional breakpoint on the `mov` to catch that case.

Comment: My understanding was that the thread context switch would preserve and restore registers such as %rax , but perhaps I am misunderstanding it.

Comment: Yes, it's not the value of `rax` being corrupted. It's the value **in memory** that is changing. It was 0 when it was loaded into `rax`, but now that you are looking at it, it's no longer 0.

Comment: Note that `mov 0x50(%r13),%rax` isn't loading the **address** of your member variable, it's loading the **contents** of that variable.  This is an indirect move, not an immediate.

Comment: The GDAL code you linked doesn't seem to show any evidence of thread-safe design.  I don't think you can expect to be able to safely access any single `GDALArrayBandBlockCache` object from multiple threads, unless you have implemented your own locking.